# NSInternalInconsistencyException Error not on STARTUP

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, tableview

I have a table view in which i have loaded elements from an SQlite database. All items load correctly. When the application was tested by the Quality Control, they discovered that : 
If a user choose a row , any row for 86 consecutive times, without performing any search, or any database interaction, the application will crash with the following error :

```
  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/eliasrahme/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/0C812075-EE27-4523-A92C-B4A4BD9A426F/App.app> (loaded)' with name 'pA3-c1-CuA-view-kK3-ii-tTp' and directory 'MainStoryboardIphone.storyboardc''

    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x23fc012 0x1509e7e 0x23fbdeb 0x359ef9 0x21e7e7 0x21edc8 0x21eff8 0x21f232 0x21f4da 0x2368e5 0x2369cb 0x236c76 0x236d71 0x23789b 0x2379b9 0x237a45 0x33d20b 0x18e2dd 0x151d6b0 0x29f8fc0 0x29ed33c 0x29f8eaf 0x22d2bd 0x175b56 0x17466f 0x174589 0x1737e4 0x17361e 0x1743d9 0x1772d2 0x22199c 0x16e574 0x16ecc1 0x1e98b 0x1a269 0x188df6 0x17bd66 0x17bf04 0x29f47d8 0x168e014 0x167e7d5 0x23a2af5 0x23a1f44 0x23a1e1b 0x23567e3 0x2356668 0x13dffc 0x1f1b 0x1da5)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

The weird thing is, this error occurs after 83 consecutive row selection, neither the error nor the weird '86' times makes any sense.
Please note that the application has a search bar, an addToFavorite button ( with interaction to the database) and a addMemo(with interaction to the database).The application is a sidepanel application ( facebook Like sliding menu).
**Edit 1:**
This is the didselectrow code : 
*N.B.* : Please note that, at any time during click on entry 1 till entry 86, if the user clicks on add memo button, the error will disappear. So I had the idea to bluff the code, and convince him that the user has clicked on AddMemo, that's why you will notice a counter on the value 75 with a simulation of a user clicking addMemo

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    notYetPressed = NO;
    DetailViewController2 *Add = [[DetailViewController2 alloc]init];



    authorNAme2 = nil;

    counterF2_2 ++;
    FirstLoadApp2 = NO;
    NSLog(@"This is the value of the counter %d" , counterF2_2);
    if(counterF2_2 == 50){


        NSLog(@"The database should be closed and free");
    }
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement442121;

    if(indexPath.row != indexPNumber){

        itemFirstTimeClicked = YES;

    }

    if(itemFirstTimeClicked){


        if(tempAuthorNameOnClick == authorNAme){

            itemFirstTimeClicked = NO;

        }
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

        firstTimeFavoritesClicked = NO;

        MenuViewController *author;

        [self->searchBar resignFirstResponder];

        if(isFiltered)
        {
            author = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }
        else
        {
            author = [theauthorsLoadedFinal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        }

        authorNAme =  author.genre;

        authorNAme2 = author.name;


        tempAuthorNameOnClick = [ authorNAme stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"
                                                                       withString:@"''"];

        NSString *formatedSql333 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select keyword from Longman where description = '%@'" , tempAuthorNameOnClick ];

        const char *sql = [formatedSql333 UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare(db2, sql, -1, &sqlStatement442121, NULL) == SQLITE_ERROR)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));
        }else{
            while ((sqlite3_step(sqlStatement442121)==SQLITE_ROW)){


                NSString *THeAuthorNameVariableByDatabase = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                                             (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement442121, 0)];


                THeAuthorNameVariableByDatabase = [ THeAuthorNameVariableByDatabase stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"''"withString:@"'"];

                                authorNAme2 = THeAuthorNameVariableByDatabase;
            }


            if(counterF2_2 == 75){

                UIStoryboard* storyboardMemo = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MemoStoryboardIphone" bundle:nil];
                UIViewController* initialHelpView2 = [storyboardMemo instantiateInitialViewController];
                //   initialHelpView2.view.superview.frame = CGRectInset(initialHelpView2.view.superview.frame, 100, 50);


                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                         selector:@selector(didDismissSecondViewController)
                                                             name:@"SecondViewControllerDismissed"
                                                           object:nil];

                initialHelpView2.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
                initialHelpView2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;  //transition shouldn't matter
                [self presentModalViewController:initialHelpView2 animated:YES];
                initialHelpView2.view.superview.frame = CGRectInset(initialHelpView2.view.superview.frame, 100, 50);

                counterF2_2 = 0;

            }



        }


    }








    else{
        if(tempAuthorNameOnClick == authorNAme){

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Same Row"
                                                           message: @"Same Row Dude"
                                                          delegate: self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"NO!"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"YES",nil];


            [alert show];
        }


        else{


            itemFirstTimeClicked = YES;

            [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

            //[self.author release];
            firstTimeFavoritesClicked = NO;


            DetailViewController2 *newInst = [[DetailViewController2 alloc]init];
            [newInst justChangeIt2];

            MenuViewController *author;

            [self->searchBar resignFirstResponder];

            if(isFiltered)
            {
                author = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            }
            else
            {
                author = [theauthorsLoadedFinal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            }
            authorNAme =  author.genre;




            tempAuthorNameOnClick = [ authorNAme stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"
                                                                           withString:@"''"];

            NSString *formatedSql333 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select keyword from Longman where description = '%@'" , tempAuthorNameOnClick ];
            const char *sql = [formatedSql333 UTF8String];







            if(sqlite3_prepare(db2, sql, -1, &sqlStatement442121, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));
            }else{
                while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement442121)==SQLITE_ROW) {


                    NSString *THeAuthorNameVariableByDatabase = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                                                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement442121, 0)];


                    THeAuthorNameVariableByDatabase = [ THeAuthorNameVariableByDatabase stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"''"
                                                                                                                  withString:@"'"];



                    authorNAme2 = THeAuthorNameVariableByDatabase;



                }

//                Add.detailItem = tempAuthorNameOnClick;
//                Add.detailItem2 = authorNAme2;
            }
            [newInst justChangeIt2];


        }


        fontValue = 50;
        startValue = 0;

        indexPNumber = indexPath.row;
        // [super viewDidLoad];
       // [self showPanelAViewController];

    }

    NSLog(@"This is the counter Value %d",counterF2_2);
    // sqlite3_close(db);
    //  }
    Add.detailItem2_2 = tempAuthorNameOnClick;
    Add.detailItem2 = authorNAme2;



    [self showPanelAViewController];


}
```

**

- Edit 2 :

**
I have symbolicated the output and this is what i got, i know that the error line is where you have on the left the application name, and on the right a specification on the line # , but it didn't make any sense...so this is the directory http://pastebin.com/z7NKDKZV,
and Error in line 34 , this is the actual code :

```
- (void) hideSideMenu
{
    // the actual animation is done by the MenuViewController
    self.window.rootViewController = self.contentViewController;
}
```

Line 35 :

```
- (void) slideThenHide
{
    // this animates the screenshot back to the left before telling the app delegate to swap out the MenuViewController
    // it tells the app delegate using the completion block of the animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        [screenShotImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
      //   SidePanelAppDelegate.window.rootViewController = SidePanelAppDelegate.contentViewController;
        [appDelegateToUse hideSideMenu];
    }];
}
```

and the one in line 48 :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

     @autoreleasepool {
    NSString *appDelegateName;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        appDelegateName =  NSStringFromClass([SidePanelAppDelegate class]);
    } else {
        appDelegateName =  NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]);
    }
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, appDelegateName);

     }
}
```

Thank you all for helping out

Comment: Without seeing code or a symbolicated stack trace, we cannot help you.

Comment: It's time to debug, investigate the problem and gather more information. btw, +1 for the Quality Control team!  ;)

Comment: I'd like to see the symbolicated stack trace to see what the actual exception is about.

Comment: how can i show you that @trojanfoe , i am not sure what you mean

Comment: @CouchDeveloper debugging didn't help me out actually therefore i had no choice but to see if anyone has any clue about this matter

Comment: You have a stack trace with numbers (addresses) which is of no use to you at all.  You need to symbolicate this stack trace so you can find out where in your app it was when it crashed.  This will save you tons of time guessing at solutions.

Comment: You should really try harder. It seems the error is reproducible. Set an "Exception breakpoint" (in Xcode's, breakpoint pane"). Do exactly what the QA team did to reveal the error. Otherwise, at least *symbolicate the stack trace* which has been gathered by the QA team.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper please check the EDit 2

Comment: @trojanfoe please check the EDit 2

Comment: Could you check, if the file `MainStoryboardIphone.storyboardc` exists in the app bundle for the *device* target? Did you possibly rename the storyboard file name (default is "Main.storyboard")?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper yea i already checked it , it exists and i removed it and re-imported it, but of course without the "c" in the end...MainStoryboardIphone.storyboard...and this happens because i have 2 storyboards, one for iPhone and the other for iPad....

Comment: @CouchDeveloper and if the problem was what u suggested, the problem then should take place and the Startup of the application, but after 83 row selections, the problem took place...

Comment: Yeah, weird! Do you have more than those two storyboard files?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper yes actually i have 4 storyboards Iphone and 4 other ones for Ipad

Comment: Well, no solution here, yet. You may verify that the basic setup is correct: the Info.plist (select target, select "Info" tab in the target editor) should contain entries for the references to the two storyboards, for iPad and iPhone separately: `"UIMainStoryboardFile (iPhone)"` `"UIMainStoryboardFile (iPad)"`. Then, check the storyboard *XML* (in Xcode: "Open As: > "Source Code") if there are any *invalid* references to other storyboard files. If you don't have "nib" main files, remove any spurious entries from the Info.plist.

Comment: Furthermore, in IB ensure that for each View Controller the flag "Initial Scene" "Is Initial View Controller" is set correctly. It shall be set only for the "initial" controllers, one View Controller for iPad one for iPhone.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I already checked everything..this is getting me really frustrated..

Comment: OK, then I would suggest to post this issue - with all relevant info - to the official Apple Developer Forum, and possibly request  a "[Developer Technical Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/).